# ¿Cómo agrego un objeto en una colección de Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo esta data, que la estoy recuperando en una colección desde mi base de datos, dentro de la colección hay un archivo de tipo resource, quiero poner por defecto un valor en esa colección y cuando recupere la demas data solo se agregue, no estoy seguro cómo hacerlo

Esta es la idea de lo quisiera.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id_value": 1,
            "value": "11111111 Admin"
        },
        {
            "id_value": 7,
            "value": "80689919 ROSA ANITA DURAND"
        },
        {
            "id_value": 8,
            "value": "21811419 LUZ YOLANDA LAOS"
        }
    ]
}
```

adjunto mi archivo collection y resource, gracias de antemano amigos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Para agregar un nuevo elemento a la colección existente puedes valerte del helper `push`<sup>1</sup> que integrará un nuevo elemento al final de la colección existente.

**Ejemplo**

Tenemos la consulta regular a un `Modelo` seleccionando 2 columnas de este mismo:

```
$consulta = Modelo::select(["columnaUno", "columnaDos"])->get();
```

Que devolvería una colección como esta:

```
[
    {
        "columnaUno": 1,
        "columnaDos": "registro1"
    },
    {
        "columnaUno": 2,
        "columnaDos": "registro2"
    },
    {
        "columnaUno": 3,
        "columnaDos": "registro3"
    },
    {
        "columnaUno": 4,
        "columnaDos": "registro4"
    },
    {
        "columnaUno": 5,
        "columnaDos": "registro5"
    },
    {
        "columnaUno": 6,
        "columnaDos": "registro6"
    }
]
```

Ahora con ayuda de una nueva propiedad llamada `$nuevoRegistro`, asignamos a `$consulta` la inserción al final de la colección existente un nuevo registro de este modo:

```
$nuevoRegistro = $consulta->push(["columnaUno" => 7, "columnaDos" => "registro7"]);
```

Que me daría como resultado una colección como la siguiente si hacemos un `return` de la misma:

```
[
    {
        "columnaUno": 1,
        "columnaDos": "registro1"
    },
    {
        "columnaUno": 2,
        "columnaDos": "registro2"
    },
    {
        "columnaUno": 3,
        "columnaDos": "registro3"
    },
    {
        "columnaUno": 4,
        "columnaDos": "registro4"
    },
    {
        "columnaUno": 5,
        "columnaDos": "registro5"
    },
    {
        "columnaUno": 6,
        "columnaDos": "registro6"
    },
    {
        "columnaUno": 7,
        "columnaDos": "registro7"
    }
]
```

**Referencia**

- <sup>1</sup>[helper `push`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-push)